# VBA Replace keyword macro

Tags: vba, excel

i just need the macro to go down the list of commands I have in my excel sheet.

basically I have a macro made in access that i need repeated per field I have to apply it to.
I was hoping to make a excel macro to make the macros for my access project and save myself alot of typing.

i need this command to replace the keywords I have which are "0" and "9"
cell B2 would go to all the "0"'s and B3 would go to all the "9"'s
then I would repeat it on the follow columns C2 & C3, D2 & D3....etc
but right now i have it to were in just does column B.

however i keep getting a "Run-time '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error no matter what I do.

```
    Sub replace()
        selection.find.clearformating
        selection.find.Replacement.clearformating
        With selection.find
            .Text = "0"
            .Replacement.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute
        End With
    selection.find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End Sub
```

that is what I have right now.

my vba code in access im planning on replacing the keywords in is this template:

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
    DoEvents
    If Me!0 = "-1" Then
    Me!9.Visible = True
    Else
    Me!9.Visible = False
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub 0_Click()
    DoEvents
    If Me!0 = "-1" Then
    Me!9.Visible = True
    Else
    Me!9.Visible = False
    End If
    End Sub
```

so let me know if you have any ideas to fix the excel macro and save me A LOT of typing.
I have about 300+ fields to make that code with.

Comment: The Range.Find method requires at least the "what" argument.  Start by amending you first two lines of code in Sub replace().  You'll notice you have supplied this for the third call to 'Find'.  Also try 'ClearFormats' rather than 'clearformatting'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK JC this should get you going.

Assumptions for this example are that:

..the data you are changing is listed in a sheet called "Data"

..the replacement keywords are stored in an a sheet called "Sheet1"

..the data keywords ("0" and "9") are stored as text values in sheet Data - you will need to deal with multi-digit 'numbers' i.e. "0" will get replaced in "0", "10", "100" etc.

..as per your Q the column numbers represent both the column of the data to be replaced AND and the column where the replacement value(s) for this column, are stored

There is no warranty that this will run in Access VBA but you should get the idea for an approach.

```
'This is the calling sub to iterate through your data
Sub callsub()
   Dim startcol As Long, endcol As Long, c As Long
   startcol = 2  'col B
   endcol = 4    'col D

    For c = startcol To endcol
        Call replace(c)  'replace keywords in Col no c
    Next c

End Sub


    'This Sub will replace two keyword values per call in the column (number) passed to it
    Sub replace(col)
        With Sheets("Data")
            repstr0 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, col)
            .Columns(col).replace What:="0", Replacement:=repstr0, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
            repstr9 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, col)
            .Columns(col).replace What:="9", Replacement:=repstr9, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
        End With
    End Sub
```

Data on the use of the `Range.Replace` method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: i have no idea how your code worked but it did perfectly, im going to go ahead and use this for the project since it will save me time and ill try and see how the heck this works, i think I need to take a VBA class LOL

thank you very much.
just wondering, why was the code i started with not able to do the same thing as your code?

Comment: just looked over the Range.Replace Method and thank you for showing me how to utilize it, i got it all setup already and done.
thank you very much again didn't take but a few mins to do with the code.

Comment: Well done J. On your Q, I think your code was using commands etc. from the Word VBA object model rather than Excel.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't specifying exactly *which line of code* is causing the error you're getting (look into "VBA Error Handling" if you're having a hard time identifying it), but I believe this:

```
.clearformating
```

Is a problem. If it's typed exactly like that in your code, either Microsoft made a typo when they named the "clear formatting" method, or you're calling a method that doesn't exist.

Also the whole search depends on what the `Selection` actually is - that might not be doing what you're expecting, where you're expecting it.

First thing to do, is to find out exactly what instruction is blowing up. When the VBA debug dialog shows up, click the [Debug] button, the illegal instruction should be highlighted in bright yellow.

Comment: The part that it highlights is the:
        `Selection.Find.Clear Formating 'added your edit`
I also have this code in a module since i doesn't even give me an error code in the workbook or worksheet objects.

Comment: I meant "formating" would be spelled "formatting", with double t's. `ClearFormatting` ;)

Comment: ya I think when I retyped it in here I accidentally mistyped it >.< sorry about that.  apparently i was using the wrong syntax here since excel VBA seems to have this other Range.Replace Method that seems to work for what I need.  darn I really wanted to at least be on the right page lol thank you for your help